# Django gis polygon field accuracy

Tags: django, python-2.7, postgis, postgresql-9.2

I'm having little difficulties making django-gis to work properly, specifically polygon field. For example, after this query:

```
select ST_AsText("zone") from somewhere where id = 56
```

I get this:

```
POLYGON((54.428907 18.487759,54.442091 18.456259,54.443189 18.434114,54.432706 18.434973,54.419225 18.432741,54.411833 18.464499,54.411735 18.487115,54.428907 18.487759))
```

But in my browser, after form rendering, I get this (on my dev server):

```
POLYGON ((54.4289070000000020 18.4877590000000000, 54.4420909999999980 18.4562589999999990, 54.4431889999999970 18.4341140000000010, 54.4327060000000030 18.4349729999999990, 54.4192249999999970 18.4327410000000000, 54.4118330000000010 18.4644990000000000, 54.4117350000000000 18.4871149999999990, 54.4289070000000020 18.4877590000000000))
```

and this on my production server:

```
POLYGON ((54.4289070000000024 18.4877590000000005, 54.4420909999999978 18.4562589999999993, 54.4431889999999967 18.4341140000000010, 54.4327060000000031 18.4349729999999994, 54.4192249999999973 18.4327410000000000, 54.4118330000000014 18.4644990000000000, 54.4117350000000002 18.4871149999999993, 54.4289070000000024 18.4877590000000005))
```

Can I somehow force polygon field to return results as shown in my first result? And where is this little difference coming from (54.4289070000000020 and 54.4289070000000024)?

I'm using postgis 2.0.2.3, python 2.7, and Django 1.6b1, postgres 9.2.4

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that because a difference of 0.000001 degrees is approximately equal to 0.111 m. (in a WGS84 projection)

Comment: You could consider asking this question on http://gis.stackexchange.com, or moving it there (as it is a GIS question). I am having problems with a similar issue as well in geodjango.